# Design pattern advice for calculating prices

Tags: oop, design-patterns, uml

I have a best practive / design pattern question. I'm working on a dispatching system where I need to calculate a price.

In the settings of the system the admin can manage 8 different rate rules. There is one for minimum fee, parking, toll, ... .

Every rule can be activated and deactivated, and every rule has its own parameters, 
for example the rule 'parking' has the parameters 'price', 'VAT', 'price per hour or fixed price', ...

I was thinking of using a Strategy pattern or Bridge pattern, but neither both fit well I think.

An other solution would be simple inheritance without using an interface.

I have modeled something, but I'm not 100% pleased with the result:

**https://www.dropbox.com/s/jllb8h0671ssq8u/RateRule-Pattern.png**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds very reasonable to me...
Whatever pattern you call it, I see a lot of sense in your idea - collection of ParkingCalculator, TollCalculator etc, with a common interface. This makes it easy to add more types of payments if they pop along the way, and it allows you to replace some pieces (e.g. different Parking policies). If the latter occurs, then it indeed falls into the classical definition of "Strategy".

Personally I'd also hide it all behind a higher-level interface of "calculateTotal" - the **current** implementation being "iterate through a collection of calculators", but the rest of the system shouldn't mind if this changes (e.g. if the rules become so complex as to require a Tree, or REST call to some external service by the Ministry of Transportation).